# Dataflow Process does not retrieve queued messages after restart

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a dataflow process subscribed to "Subscribtion A" on a "Topic A" processing messages in streaming mode.

According to PubSub documentation, if the messages are not pulled they will be retained for at least 7 days per subscription. Am I right to assume that if I stop my Dataflow process for an hour and then restart, it should process all the messages accumulated in the subscription while subscriber process was down before proceeding with the streaming messages?

In our case Dataflow process does not seem to pick up queued messages after restart. Is there any explicit configuration option that we are missing?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, Dataflow should handle such downtime transparently, and process all the backlog when you start the pipeline again. Could you tell more about how you're detecting that Dataflow did not process the queued messages? A job ID would help.

Comment: Also, since you said you stop your pipeline for an hour, I wonder if you might be interested in the pipeline update feature (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline).

Comment: Are you reading from a Topic or a Subscription? If you specify a topic, Dataflow will create a fresh subscription when the job starts, in which case it wouldn't have any buffered messages (the messages are retained per-subscription).

Answer (score 1):

We tested it again and it does seem to work fine. It appears to be related to some other issues.